# Creating a matrix using lists Python

Tags: python, matrix

In Python, matrices can be created using nested lists. For example, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]. Below I have written a function that prompts the user for the dimensions of a square matrix and then prompts the user for the values in the for loop. I have a tempArray variable that temporarily stores one row of values, and then is deleted after it is appended to the matrix array. For some reason, when I print the matrix at the end, this is what I get: [ [ ], [ ] ]. What is going wrong?

```
def proj11_1_a():
    n = eval(input("Enter the size of the square matrix: "))
    matrix = []
    tempArray = []   

    for i in range(1, (n**2) + 1):
        val = eval(input("Enter a value to go into the matrix: "))

        if i % n == 0:
            tempArray.append(val)
            matrix.append(tempArray)
            del tempArray[:]
        else:
            tempArray.append(val)
    print(matrix)
proj11_1_a()
```

Comment: there is no printing in this code

Comment: Sorry I deleted that line

Comment: why do you delete your array? `del tempArray[:]`

Comment: the array is only deleted after it has one row of values. The reason why it is deleted is so it can then store the next row of values and then append it to the matrix array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply delete the array elements `del tempArray[:]` and as lists are **mutable** it also clears part of `matrix`

```
def proj11_1_a():
    n = eval(input("Enter the size of the square matrix: "))
    matrix = []
    tempArray = []   

    for i in range(1, (n**2) + 1):
        val = eval(input("Enter a value to go into the matrix: "))

        if i % n == 0:
            tempArray.append(val)
            matrix.append(tempArray)
            tempArray = [] #del tempArray[:]
        else:
            tempArray.append(val)
    print(matrix)
proj11_1_a()
```

Which could be further simplified/cleared to

```
def proj11_1_a():
    # Using eval in such place does not seem a good idea
    # unless you want to accept things like "2*4-2"
    # You might also consider putting try: here to check for correctness

    n = int(input("Enter the size of the square matrix: "))
    matrix = []

    for _ in range(n): 
        row = []   

        for _ in range(n): 
            # same situation as with n
            value = float(input("Enter a value to go into the matrix: "))
            row.append(value)

        matrix.append(row)

    return matrix
```

Comment: you will be doing the append(val) anyways so it is better to get it out from the if/else blocks

Comment: @Jjpx - it is OP code, only fragment causing the problem was changed, there are many things here which could be improved

Comment: As @Jjpx suggested, you could provide optimal version as well. I think it would be beneficial to the OP to have both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to change the following line:

```
matrix.append(tempArray)
```

to:

```
matrix.append(tempArray.copy())
```

Comment: which is suboptimal as you need to ... copy the object (thus if it is large, it takes linear time).

Comment: As the original intention was to prompt user for the input, overhead is minimal compared to the speed of the user input.

Comment: Sure, but it does not mean one should write insufficient code elsewhere. Neither should we suggest it to people learning python (like OP)